# Azure IoT Central - cannot export to event hub - "Starting..."

Tags: azure-iot-central

I am trying to export device telemetry from my IoT Central app to an Event Hub.  When I create a 'Data Export' and point it to my (existing) Event Hub, I see message

```
Starting (this may take a few minutes)
```

for about 10 minutes and then eventually I see

```
Stopped because of errors
```

There does not appear to be any place where I can see the actual error.

My application is set up with a Gateway device, with 2 **simulated** template devices (S1 and RS40 sensors) underneath the Gateway.  I set up my Data Export to point to an existing Event Hub, and only selected 'telemetry' for export. While the 'Starting' message is displayed in the Data Export list, I see repeated device ModelDefinition messages pile up in the Event Hub (viewed using Service Bus Explorer), then it stops.  No telemetry messages, however.

I do see telemetry messages getting into IoT Central using:

```
az iot central app monitor-events --app-id <app_id> --properties all
```

And I see the various device views showing the simulated data with IoT Central itself.

Is there anyway I can see why the Data Export creation error?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @cardinalPilot have you checked to make sure that the connection string is valid or that the connection string has enough permissions to create the export? With minimal information about your application we can't debug the issue. If the connection string is the correct one, then I'd encourage you to submit a support ticket so that we can further look into this.

From docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-export-data):

Event Hubs or Service Bus, go to the namespace in the Azure portal:

- Under Settings, select Shared Access Policies
- Choose the default RootManageSharedAccessKey or create a new one
- Copy either the primary or secondary connection string

Thanks,
Luis on behalf of the IoT Central team.